# curses.wrapper() messing up terminal after background/foreground sequence

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I am investigating a bug where `curses.wrapper` does not restore the terminal properly. The issue is shown after a backgrounding/foregrounding sequence.

Consider the following python program saved in `myprogram.py`:

```
import curses, subprocess

# Function that does nothing
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

curses.wrapper(f)

# Call vi to open a file 
subprocess.call("vi /tmp/foo", shell=True)
```

Steps to repro the issue:

1. Run the program: `python myprogram.py`
2. It starts vi editing the file `/tmp/foo`
3. When I hit `ctrl-z` it brings me back to my shell
4. When I resume the program with `fg`
5. It restarts the editor but the screen is wrong (all black and the editor is not drawn)

**Removing the `curses.wrapper(f)` line makes the program works: the editor is drawn properly when the program is resumed.**

I tried multiple things, like replacing the call to `curses.wrapper(f)` by what it actually does and, the most minimal example (i.e. calling `initscr`, `endwin`) leads also to the same issue.

I am running:

- zsh 5.0.5, I also tried the latest fish shell version
- python 2.7.6
- VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

This happens to be a bug in `curses.wrapper` or anything underneath that forgets to restore signal handler to their previous values.
This fixes it:

```
import curses, subprocess
import signal

# Function that does nothing
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

a = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGTSTP)

curses.wrapper(f)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, a)

# Call vi to open a file 
subprocess.call("vi /tmp/oo", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

The source-code for [curses.wrapper](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/curses/__init__.py#L63) does nothing special with signals.

During initialization (such as a call to [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html)), the ncurses library adds handlers for these signals: `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGTSTP`, `SIGWINCH`. For whatever reason (likely because it is an internal detail not directly visible to callers), this is documented mainly in the [`NEWS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html) file.

Applications which need to add their own signal handler should do this after ncurses' initialization (since ncurses does this only once).  Because curses applications can be switched to/from screen-mode, the signal handlers are left active until the program quits.  For instance, it would be possible for a Python script to call `curses.wrapper` more than once (although it probably would not work correctly except with ncurses -- X/Open says that "[portable applications must not
call **initscr** more than once](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h2-PORTABILITY)").

Saving and restoring the signal handler state as suggested by [@lc2817](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988828/lc2817) will work—but it *is* a workaround because it is not elegant.  If `curses.wrapper` were modified to add some state to it, to remember if it was called before, and to save/restore the signal-handlers, the workaround would be unnecessary.  To make it really portable, `initscr` should be called on the first use, and `refresh` on subsequent uses.